# ActionProvider with custom views instead of menu items?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

Is it possible to create an ActionBar ActionProvider in Android 3.0+ with custom views for the menu items? So far I have seen these with icons and text, and text with a checkbox, but would it be posible to inflate an arbitrary view instead?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "menu items", do you mean the overflow menu?

Comment: I don't think I mean that. Take for example the ShareActionProvider. When you use one of those it pops down a menu with icons and text for each item. Can you replace these with custom views? Or are you stuck with just menu items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ShareActionProvider` indirectly uses `PopupWindow`, which can hold whatever you want.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I see that it creates an ActivityChooserView, which creates a ListPopupWindow which is a standard list and gets its views from an adapter as per usual. Thanks for the push in the right direction.